# Items mixed on one place

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I have problem with layout of listview items...

I have simple model with 3 items.

Code is here:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2


Page
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    background:Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "transparent"
    }

    ListModel
    {
    id: diaryModel
    ListElement
    {
        diaryName: "Bill Smith"
        diaryNumber: "555 3264"
    }
    ListElement
    {
        diaryName: "John Brown"
        diaryNumber: "555 8426"
    }
    ListElement
    {
        diaryName: "Sam Wise"
        diaryNumber: "555 0473"
    }
}

ListView
{
    id: diaryListView
    model: diaryModel
    currentIndex: 0
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true
    clip: true

    highlightResizeDuration: 0.0
    highlight: Rectangle
    {
        color: "#2e6377"
        gradient:Gradient
        {
            GradientStop {position: 0.000;color: "#0c0e0f";}
            GradientStop {position: 0.500;color: "#15171a";}
            GradientStop {position: 1.000;color: "#0c0e0f";}

        }
    }
    delegate: hDelegate
}

Component
{
    id: hDelegate
    Item
    {
        Row
        {
            Rectangle
            {
                color: "green"
                width: 60
                height: 60
            }
            Text
            {
                text: diaryName
                color: "lightsteelblue"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font {pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1}
            }
            Text
            {
                text: diaryNumber
                color: "lightsteelblue"
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font {pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1}
            }
        }
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onClicked:
            {
                diaryListView.currentIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Problem is, that my items are mixed on one place...

I don't understand generaly anchors and padding and placing objects...
When I tested how anchors, borders, spacing etc... works on each objects as Component, Item or Rectangle, i get unexepted results, because:

in `component` I cannot use `anchors.fill: parent`(error - property not exists).

when I use `anchors.fill: parent` in `Item`, it cause that application completly stop response. (I thing it's in endless cycle?)

When I use spacing or padding to create spaces between two objects (rectangle and text item) application do nothing. Still showing all objects without spaces (see picture).

What I doing wrong?

[image]

Ideally I can make sometihng like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not give a size to a Component, since the Component is not an `Item` that has any dimensions. It is just wraps a prototype of, e.g. an Item.

So instead of resizing the `Component`, give the `Item` in that Component a size.

```
Component {
    id: hDelegate
    Item {
        width: parent.width // You can access the parent this Item will have uppon creation
        height: hRow.implicitHeight // You can also resize it according to the content.
        Row {
            id: hRow
            Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                width: 60
                height: 60
            }
            Text {
                text: diaryName
                color: "lightsteelblue"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font { pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1 }
            }
            Text {
                text: diaryNumber
                color: "lightsteelblue"
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                font { pointSize: 14; letterSpacing: 1; wordSpacing: 1 }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onClicked: {
                diaryListView.currentIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parent of the `Item` won't be the `Component`. It will be the `ListView` in your case, might be the parent of a `Repeater` in some other case, or `null` if you call `createObject()` without specifying a parent.

---

The reason why you should not set the `Item` to `anchors.fill: parent` is simply because the parent will resize its `contentItem` to fit all the children one after another. If all the children then will resize to fill the `contentItem` by them selves, this forces the `ListView` to resize the `contentItem`, so that all (3) children will fit in again...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.